# Ubuntu Nginx 403 error when posting form data including <iframe>

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, iframe, nginx, http-status-code-403

I have a Ubuntu Nginx server (using laravel forge to set it up)

I am now getting 403 errors when posting form data including  which I was not getting previously.

The form is posted by a javascript button $('#my-form').submit(); if this is relevant.

Other forms are working fine as long as I remove the  tags (used for youtube embedding)

Answer (score 0):

Open up developer console and see more details about the POST request in network tab or console itself. 4XX is a group for client errors, not server or runtime, so expect the issue to be in your implementation. Maybe you use some package that is supposed to "automagically" authenticate or check user permissions when accepting this specific request, and so it fails because you are not passing some header or custom field? Hard to tell without more details.
Add relevant code (at very least your form html) if you want more specific tips.

Comment: It's a server issue. The page in question is an admin page.. so even when I logout, and a refresh on the other tab (posting it again) it gives the 404. If it hit the script it would redirect.

As mentioned above.. it is only when <iframe> is used within posted textarea fields. Posting the form otherwise - works fine

Comment: 403* that was meant to be

Answer (score 0):

In this case - I also had a wordpress blog installed with a wordfence plugin operating. The wordfence configuration was enforcing security settings which were preventing *any* website forms from posting  and  tags